# php linux regex how to match if cron process is running?

Tags: php, regex, process, cron

I want to run only one proccess at a time. So I need to check. I found there was suggestions to use exec()

so I made test functions - one which sleeps 1 minute and one which tests if process is running.

```
public function test($a='', $b='') {
    exec("ps ax | grep 'php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2'", $pids);
    if (count($pids) > 2) { 
        $exists = true;
        echo 'exists' . count($pids);

    print_r($pids);

    }
}
```

And I get result:

```
exists3Array
(
    [0] => 30680 pts/8    S+     0:00 php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2
    [1] => 30684 ?        S      0:00 sh -c ps ax | grep 'php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2'
    [2] => 30686 ?        S      0:00 grep php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2
)
```

I did not expect 3 processes but I see its ok. Can I be sure that my function is working ok - detecting running when there is > 2, am I not missing something? For example maybe if some user will run some program on linux maybe this will not work anymore?

Or can you sugesst some check which matches only the one process, without sh and grep? I mean exact string. I was trying but cannot make it work to match only one which I am searching.

Edit:

googled bit more and found more examples, adjusted and have this:

```
exec ('ps -efa | grep "php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2" |grep -v "grep " | awk "{print $10 $NF}"',  $pids);
    print_r($pids);
```

When process runs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => darius    2046 12877  5 09:23 pts/8    00:00:00 php -q /var/www/glab/index.php ajax/test2
)
```

It matches now 1 processs. Could you check if this is ok, am I not missing something?

Comment: If you want to make sure a script only runs once at a given time (no concurrency) then the usual approach is to implement locking. Use a lock in the file system: a starting script `touches` a file (say in /var/lock/...) and rmeoves that lock again when finishing. Other started instances first check if such a lock already exists and bail out if so.

Comment: Write a pid file and if it still exists and is current exit without running again

Comment: The lock is bad. I think its the same as if I set in a database field state. THe problem is - what if script crashes? It does not release the lock and will never start unless manually unlocking. @Anigel - you mean write the process number in the file and delete file after script finishes? That has the same problem.

Comment: Please explain why you think it is bad. You are probably not understanding the concept or we are not understanding your requirement. Personally I would have said relying on exec was bad

Comment: I mean - I run script. And some php or database error happens. Might be rare thing because the more time system runs, the more it gets tested but still its not possible to be 100% guaranteed that script will not stop. And it might not have reached the point where it realeases the lock, or deletes file, or sets state in database. And I don't get why exec is bad? I have read that its only bad when we let user inject the string.

Comment: Then you use [exception handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and delete the file before the script closes...

Comment: actually the problem was that I am working on codeigniter framework and when there is database error - it shows error but does not catch any exception. But then I tried db_debug to turn off, and then it just skips and continues running the code. So it means then I can use exceptions, in production db_debug is turned off anyway. So I dont even need a file then, can use as I was done before - setting state in db.